# Are "gratitude" and "appreciation" suitable CC-CEDICT definitions for 感激之心?

Tags: meaning

In my writing, my teacher suggested I use 感激之心.  I didn't find 感激之心 in [CC-CEDICT](https://cc-cedict.org/wiki/start), although there is

> 感激 感激 [gan3 ji1] /to be grateful/to appreciate/thankful/

It seems reasonable to create a definition for it (there are comparable definitions for 恻隐之心 and 赤子之心), and 感激 is a verb whereas 感激之心 is a noun.  It means something like "gratitude" or "appreciation", but let's give this a peer review.

Proposed definition:

> 感激之心 感激之心 [gan3 ji1 zhi1 xin1] /gratitude/appreciation/

**Question**: Is this a suitable CC-CEDICT definition for 感激之心?

---

CC-CEDICT definitions are *high-quality*: they are proofread and edited prior to being added; ideally we can minimize this editorial work.

They have the form

> [traditional Chinese] [simplified Chinese] [pinyin] [definitions, separated by '/']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"感激之心" literally is "the heart that is grateful/appreciated/thankful". And I think it should be kept that way, which is a phrase not a word. Its meaning can be derive from words in the phrase easily. I don't think it should have its own entry.

"恻隐之心" has its own entry, probably because "恻隐" is seldom used alone now. "恻隐之心" has become a set phrase, or a word.

"赤子之心" is different, it means "the heart of ...", and it has its own figurative meaning which is different from that of "赤子". So it got its own entry.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that be 感激之情？

小明帮小红修好了她的自行车后，小红对小明充满了感激之情。

Comment: My personal view is that 感激之心 has a wider more general application, whereas 感激之情 is more personal and thus a narrower application。